# Зеркала сайта - SEO

Tags: seo, зеркало

Такой вопрос: Если к примеру я продвигаю в топ 1 сайт, его блокируют, но у него есть зеркала в другой доменной зоне, сайт выкинут с выдачи по запросам и зеркала не будут показываться тоже (их отдельно продвигать надо?) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отдельно - зеркало обеспечивает доступность, но не продвижение - в противном случае зеркалами одного сайта был  весь топ занят, к примеру.

Продвигаете ведь не просто сайт - а сайт, расположенный на домене, потому домен, в продвижении === сайт.

- Продвигать одновременно два и более доменов по одним и тем же запросам смысла нет - во-первых, ПС их склеят, при достаточной одинаковости контента и тд.;
  во-вторых - внутренний каннибализм - будут мешать друг другу и зацепится, возможно, не тот домен, который бы предпочитали.

Поэтому, с помощью 301 редиректа можно передать с заблокированного всю бороду и трафик по ссылкам и по устойчивым посетителям, но в выдаче новый/зеркало нужно будет продвигать.